# DPD webiste using almost 100% of CPU

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, cpu-usage

Currently sat in the DPD Live chat page waiting for someone to respond. But my PC is at its limit...

Thought something was wrong when I heard the fans ramp up to full, checked task manager and Chrome is utilizing 90-95%. It only seems to be this specific page (`dpd.co.uk/apps/tracking/?parcel=<MYPARCELNUMBER>*XXXXX&geoSession=<SESSIONID?>`)

I'm afraid I wouldn't know where to begin working out what's causing it. The only thing of note is Chrome's TM indicates that GPU Process is using it for the majority. Only extensions I'm running are uBlock Origin and Ears: volume equalizer.

More of a curiosity thing than a desire to fix, for the most part the only time I've heard of things like this happening are crypto miners; but given the site it's probably something else.

Cheers

EDIT: As an afterthought I tried the exact same URL in incognito, same thing there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, did a bit of research, and it appears to be really bad GPU intensive programming for the animation shown at the top of the tracking page.

See the following gif:
[image]

I can't just remove the text from Inspect, as Javascript keeps putting it back. Disabling Javascript for this site fixes the issue though, and the text is not added, and the image is gone from the site too.